# Rotation from quaternion to glmatrix axis rotation

Tags: quaternions

I have my own webgl library with scene objects who have position and rotation.
I use for physics cannon.js library. In cannon.js for rotation logic it is used `quaternion`.
My engine runs on simple local axis rotation (rotation.rotx ...).

This is most important part of code for this problem:

Part from render:

```js
    while(physicsLooper <= world.contentList.length - 1) {
      if(world.contentList[physicsLooper].physics.enabled) {
        var local = world.contentList[physicsLooper];

        local.position.SetX(local.physics.currentBody.position.x)
        local.position.SetZ(local.physics.currentBody.position.y)
        local.position.SetY(local.physics.currentBody.position.z)
        world.contentList[physicsLooper].rotation.rotx = radToDeg(local.physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[1]);
        world.contentList[physicsLooper].rotation.roty = radToDeg(local.physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[1]);
        world.contentList[physicsLooper].rotation.rotz = radToDeg(local.physics.currentBody.quaternion.toAxisAngle()[1]);
        // matrixEngine.matrixWorld.world.physics.toDeg
      }
      physicsLooper++;
    }
```

Also i can access `toAxisAngle()[0]` :

```js
quaternion.toAxisAngle()[0].x
quaternion.toAxisAngle()[0].y
quaternion.toAxisAngle()[0].z
```

For example i have very close to the right solution but steel not perfect...

Example link for visual feel:
[Navigate to the `Physics class - Cube` example](https://maximumroulette.com/apps/matrix-engine/examples-build.html)
Source code: [matrix-engine](https://github.com/zlatnaspirala/matrix-engine)

Any suggestion , will be very glad for any math suggestion?

Comment: The axis angles are called euler angles... Check this out: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles have in mind that the order of multiplying the euler angles is very important.